# Lost access to Blockchain dot info ticker

Tags: bitcoin

it seems they have implemented some kind of DDOS prevention software and I can no longer access the ticker.  does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: incidentally, it was working fine until this morning.  the error I get is "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the service is working this morning so I guess it has nothing to do with the DDOS software but was probably a transient error.  what gets me is that I could pull up the ticker from my browser but not from code, which is why I wrote.  but it's working today